# Django signals: Sending signals to a class without direct relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, signals

How can I have count `-=1` in `count` field in `class Purchased_lessons`, when I delete a `Watched_lessons` object?

watched_lessons/models.py

```
from lessons.models import lesson
from django.conf import settings
from purchased_lessons.models import Purchased_lessons
from datetime import datetime
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

class Watched_lessons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Statement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    watched_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lesson
```

The other codes:

lesson/models.py

```
from courses.models import Course

class Lesson(models.Model):   
    course = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    lesson = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lesson
```

courses/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

purchased_lessons/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings
from courses.models import Course


class Purchased_lessons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0) #tracks the amount of lessons watched per course and by a particular user.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course
```

Comment: Firstly, I can't understand why you think a Watched_lessons instance would have a purchased_lessons attribute. Purchased_lessons is connected with user and course, not with Watched_lessons. But secondly, I don't know why you want to keep the count in a field, rather than simply counting whatever you need to count when you need to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I know there is no Watched_lessons instance would not have a purchased_lessons attribute.

I really need to keep counting in a field.

If you notice, in the "count" field I will record the amount of lessons purchased by each user. Then, if a user cancels a lesson, that user's "Watched_lesson" will be canceled, and therefore should enter the "-1" in the "count" field.



So. I just need to know if it is possible to somehow send the "-1" to the "count" field in the "Purchased_lessons" attribute when I delete a "Watched_lesson".

Comment: @Felipe but can a user purchase the same course multiple times? a `Purchased_lesson` is a relationship between a `User` and **one** `Course`. What is `count` tracking exactly? And as Daniel said, there's no relationship between `Watched_lessons` and a `Purchased_lessons`. Via the `user`, there's a relationship to multiple `Purchased_lessons` objects: `watched_lesson.user.purchased_lessons_set.all()`. You want to reduce the count on all of them?

Comment: @dirkgroten , 'count' do not tracking amount of courses. 'count' tracking amount of watched lessons by a given user. I will edit for ease of understanding.

Comment: `count` tracks the amount of lessons watched per course and by a particular user.

Comment: Why don't you just have `Purchased_lesson` being a m2m relationship between `User` and `Lesson` (instead of `Course`). That way, each time a user purchases a lesson, you create the m2m relationship and it's easy to count how many lessons a user purchased for a course:  `user.lesson_set.filter(course=somecourse).count()`. And the count is automatically correct.

Comment: @dirkgronten, I can not do this because the user is required to purchase all the lessons of the course. The user only can purchase the complete courses with all lessons.

So, if the user don't like some lesson, he can cancel that specific lesson.